# PHP orientado a Objetos - Ejercicio Cafetera

Tags: php, poo

Estimados, me encuentro un poco confundido con este ejercicio de PHP.

Desarrolla una clase Cafetera con atributos _capacidadMaxima (la cantidad 
máxima de café que puede contener la cafetera) y _cantidadActual (la cantidad 
actual de café que hay en la cafetera).

Implementa, al menos, los siguientes métodos:

- Constructor predeterminado: establece la capacidad máxima en 1000 (c.c.)
  y la actual en cero (cafetera vacía).
- llenarCafetera(): pues eso, hace que la cantidad actual sea igual a la
  capacidad.
- servirTaza(int): simula la acción de servir una taza con la capacidad 
  indicada.  Si la cantidad actual de café “no alcanza” para llenar la taza, se 
  sirve lo que quede.
- vaciarCafetera(): pone la cantidad de café actual en cero.
- agregarCafe(int): añade a la cafetera la cantidad de café indicada.

De momento, lo que tengo es esto y pero me da errores

```
<?php

class Cafetera {
    public $capacidadMaxima;
    public $CantidadActual;

    public function __construct($capacidadMaxima,$CantidadActual)
    {
        $this->$capacidadMaxima = $capacidadMaxima;
        $this->CantidadActual = $CantidadActual;
    }

    public function llenarCafetera()
    {
        $this->CantidadActual = capacidadMaxima; 
    }   

    public function servirTaza($LlenarTaza)
    {
        if($LlenarTaza > $this->CantidadActual) {
            echo 'No alcanza para una taza. Recargá la cafetera!';
        } else {
            $this->CantidadActual -= $LlenarTaza;
        }
    }


    public function vaciarCafetera()
    {
        $this->CantidadActual = 0; 
    }   

    public function agregarCafe($rellenar)
    {
        $this->CantidadActual = $rellenar; 
    }   

    public function Mostrar()
    {
        echo 'Capacidad Máxima: '. $capacidadMaxima.'<br>';
        echo 'Capacidad Actual: '. $CantidadActual.'<br>';
    }
}

$cafetera = new Cafetera(1000,0);
$cafetera->servirTaza(200);
$cafetera->agregarCafe(150);
$cafetera->mostrar();

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, que errores te marca al ejecutar tu script?

Comment: Ojo con la utilización de $ y la no utilización de $

Answer (score 1):

Este es tu código corregido:

```
<?php

class Cafetera {
    private $capacidadMaxima;
    private $cantidadActual;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->capacidadMaxima = 1000;
        $this->cantidadActual = 0;
    }

    public function llenarCafetera(){
        $this->cantidadActual = $this->capacidadMaxima; 
    }   

    public function servirTaza($capacidadTaza) {
        if($capacidadTaza > $this->cantidadActual) {
            echo 'No alcanza para una taza. Recargá la cafetera!<br>';
        } else {
            $this->cantidadActual -= $capacidadTaza;
        }
    }


    public function vaciarCafetera() {
        $this->cantidadActual = 0; 
    }   

    public function agregarCafe($rellenar) {
        // esto agrega café por lo tanto debe ser +=
        $this->cantidadActual += $rellenar;

        // si se excede, dejar en el maximo
        if($this->cantidadActual > $this->capacidadMaxima){
            $this->cantidadActual = $this->capacidadMaxima;
        }
    }   

    public function mostrar() {
        echo 'Capacidad Máxima: ' . $this->capacidadMaxima . '<br>';
        echo 'Capacidad Actual: ' . $this->cantidadActual . '<br>';
    }
}

$cafetera = new Cafetera(1000,0);
$cafetera->servirTaza(200);
$cafetera->agregarCafe(150);
$cafetera->mostrar();

?>
```

Como dice la respuesta anterior, te faltan algunos `this`. Siempre que te refieras a un atributo de la clase desde la misma clase debes anteponer el `this`. [Puedes leerlo en la documentación.](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php)

Lo otro es que entiendo que tu requisito debe usar un [contructor](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php) sin parámetros, ya que dice:

> Constructor predeterminado: establece la capacidad máxima en 1000 (c.c.)
>   y la actual en cero (cafetera vacía).

También he cambiado la [visibilidad](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php) de tus atributos a privados y el método de `agregarCafe()`.

Answer (score 0):

te falta el `$this->`

aqui:

```
public function llenarCafetera()
    {
    $this->CantidadActual = $this->capacidadMaxima; 
    }
```

y aqui:

```
public function Mostrar()
    {
    echo 'Capacidad Máxima: '. $this->capacidadMaxima.'<br>';
    echo 'Capacidad Actual: '. $this->CantidadActual.'<br>';
     }
```